# Getting a RichTextCtrl's default font size in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a `RichTextCtrl`, which I've modified to accept HTML input. The HTML parsing code needs to be able to increase and decrease the font size as it gets tags like `<font size="-1">`, but I can't work out how to get the control's default font size to adjust.
I tried the following (where `self` is my `RichTextCtrl`):

```
fred = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
self.GetStyle(0,fred)
print fred.GetFontSize()
```

However, the final instruction fails, because GetStyle turns `fred` into a `TextAttrEx` and so I get `AttributeError: 'TextAttrEx' object has no attribute 'GetFontSize'`. Am I missing a vastly easier way of getting the default font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out. Before any data is written to the control:

```
self.defaultstyle = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
self.GetStyle(self.GetInsertionPoint(), self.defaultstyle)
self.defaultsize = self.defaultstyle.GetFont().GetPointSize()
```